# Print season exercise with system date (sy-datum)

Tags: abap

I need to write a program which takes the system date (sy-datum)& displays the season of the year for the next 8 years.

WRITE: ‘The current season is’, season
where you add three months to your date and print the season &
the date. Stop the loop when the end of the year 2020.
Note : need to USE ABAP

Comment: What have you tried, and what specific problems are you having implementing that?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to be asking someone to do their work for them. Does not show any prior effort or problem with a piece of code. (Why did they remove that option from Off-Topic closing?)

Answer (score 1):

I am of course assuming your system has the function module ISP_MONTHS_TO_DATE, if that is not the case you should search for * month* in SE37, there are a ton of function modules for adding months to dates ( if you attempt to do this yourself, you will have bugs ).

```
REPORT zdemo.

DATA : l_date TYPE sy-datum.
DATA : l_season TYPE string.

l_date = sy-datum.

PERFORM get_season USING l_date CHANGING l_season.

WRITE: 'The current season is', l_season. NEW-LINE.

DO.

  CALL FUNCTION 'ISP_ADDING_MONTHS_TO_DATE'
    EXPORTING
      months     = 3
      start_date = l_date
    IMPORTING
      end_date   = l_date.

  IF l_date(4) GT 2020.
    EXIT.
  ENDIF.

  PERFORM get_season USING l_date CHANGING l_season.

  WRITE: 'The season on', l_date , 'is' , l_season. NEW-LINE.

ENDDO.

*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*&      Form  get_seasons
*&---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*       text
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
*      -->DATE       text
*      -->SEASON     text
*----------------------------------------------------------------------*
FORM get_season USING p_date TYPE sydatum CHANGING p_season TYPE string.

  IF p_date+4 LT '0321'.
    l_season = 'Winter'.
  ELSEIF p_date+4 LT '0621'.
    l_season = 'Spring'.
  ELSEIF p_date+4 LT '0921'.
    l_season = 'Summer'.
  ELSEIF p_date+4 LT '1221'.
    l_season = 'Fall'.
  ELSE.
    l_season = 'Winter'.
  ENDIF.

ENDFORM.                    "get_season
```

Comment: The season depends on the part of the hemisphere you live in, so the `get_season` procedure should be somehow enhanced.

Comment: Rana David would have to figure that out himself for extra credit ;)

Comment: Also this is does not support another language than english :) Perhaps using a message that can then be translated instead of strings. more "enterprise" this way.

Answer (score 0):

I think `CL_RECA_DATE` is the moneymaker you're looking for.  See this example.

```
DATA: l_date   TYPE sydatum,
      l_season TYPE string.

l_date = sy-datum.

WHILE l_date(4) <= 2020.
  WRITE /: 'The current season is'.

  CASE l_date+4(2).
    WHEN 1 or 2 or 12.  l_season = 'Spring'(001).
    WHEN 3 or 4 or 5.   l_season = 'Summer'(002).
    WHEN 6 or 7 or 8.   l_season = 'Fall'(003).
    WHEN 9 or 10 or 11. l_season = 'Winter'(004).
  ENDCASE.

  WRITE: l_season, l_date.

  l_date = cl_reca_date=>add_months_to_date( id_date   = l_date
                                             id_months = 3 ).
ENDWHILE.
```

Getting the season can be done with a `CASE` statement if .  The example above assumes December-February is winter, you might want to modify that if you have different requirements.  For the astronomical definition of the seasons, you can parse `l_date+4` with `IF...ELSEIF`.

Answer (score -1):

There are a lot of function modules available in the function builder to add months in the date and return the new date .use them to determine the date and then use another function to calculate the current month.Compare them to determine the season and hence problem solved.